# Invalid predicate error due to double quote inside an html attribute

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, double-quotes

I have the following html script:

```
<body class="item"> <a title="spre_|_"Marketing_|_Specialist""> Marketing Specialist </a> </body>
```

As you can see in `<a>` tag, the value of title attribute has double quotes inside the main quotes. When I use `beautifulsoup` to get the element using xpath, I keep getting this error:

```
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 2314, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 357, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate
```

This is my code:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO
html_ = """<body class="loop"> <a title="spre_|_"Marketing_|_Specialist""> Marketing Specialist </a> </body>"""
xpath = """//a[@title="spre_|_"Marketing_|_Specialist""][1]"""
print(etree.parse(StringIO(html_), etree.HTMLParser()).xpath(xpath))
```

I tried to escape the double quotes with `\`, but nothing change.

Comment: The correct way to escape characters in HTML is with [HTML entities](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Entity).

Comment: @SebastianSimon, to be like this: `//a[@title="spre_|_&quot;Marketing_|_Specialist&quot;"][1]` ?  I just tried, it didn't work.

Comment: i think that's invalid html and all parsers should fail. regex looks like a good tool here

Comment: @diggusbickus, why it's invalid?

Comment: i thought i'd read too fast and deleted my comment but it's ok. [html5 specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attributes-2) (Double-quoted attribute value syntax §) if you're using `"` to enclose your value you can't use `"` in it

Comment: Thanks! yes this is what I just found, This is fine: `....title='spre_|_"Marketing_|_Specialist"'> M...`.